# Application Id for android application?

Tags: android

i need to fetch the application for android application, how to fetch that app id , i got that app id using Urban air ship ,it is of the form "ab4f3aa5-b169-4fed-82bc-ce6c39240517
" , whereas i need to fetch this one using native code, if there is any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this ID standard ? I thought package name was unique and the main ID for apps.

To get the package name of an app, use

```
activity.getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().packageName;
```

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: me also don`t know, similar to unique package name , there may be unique ID